# Android how to create a fillable bar/meter and fill it in java?

Tags: android

I want to create an Android `Activity` having a power bar and a `Button`, such that whenever i click the `Button`, the power bar gets filled by say 10% of its total height.
What  Android widget to use for a power bar ?
And how to update its fill?

Answer (score 1):

```
progress=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        plus=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        minus=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                if(v==plus)
                {
                    progress.incrementProgressBy(10);
                    setProgress(100*progress.getProgress());
                }

            }
        });

        minus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v1) 
            {
                if(v1==minus)
                {
                    progress.incrementProgressBy(-10);
                    setProgress(90*progress.getProgress());
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: You can also increment and also decrement progress

Comment: And I want it to have a custom look, so how can i achieve that?

Comment: i dont know what u do but seek bar is also work in horizontal to show progress is better than seek

Comment: Is there anyway to make the progress bar have a custom look?

Comment: Prayas, look at the source code for Progress bar, and see how it is implemented - they you will be able to figure out how to customize it.  It is easy to change the size and color, not sure about other appearance